# Pagina mostra apenas os arquivos no IIS 7 Aplicação MVC 5

Tags: c#, mvc, iis

possuo uma aplicação Mvc 5, para desenvolvimento utilizei o IIS Express, tudo funciona normalmente nele, porém estou um problema para subir no IIS 7. Ainda na minha máquina local, posteriormente levarei ao Windows 2008. O problema é que ao rodar `http://localhost/Aprovacoes/` minha página não abre, abre apenas os arquivos como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configuração de acesso a pasta inetpub onde se encontra o publish do projeto está com acesso, ja foi testado no iis.

Já testei com todos os pools de aplicativos, atualmente está setado o 4.0 Integrated.

Meu route config não fiz nenhuma alteração, está da seguinte maneira:

```
public static class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
            routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }).RouteHandler = new DashRouteHandler();
        }
    }
```

Já tentei adicionar documento padrão Index.cshtml no iis mas também não deu certo.

Ao acessar o Home/Index, a action vai identificar que não há usuário logado pelo Forms Authentication, e irá redirecionar para a Account/Login, todo este processo funciona no IIS Express.

Poderiam me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para solucionar isto, você precisa acessar a pasta do Windows onde está instalada a versão do seu Asp.net. Faça os seguintes passos:

Abra o prompt de comando como administrador

Acesse:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.30319
```

após isto execute o comando `aspnet_regiis.exe -i`

irá lhe apresentar da seguinte maneira no prompt

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319>
Microsoft (R) ASP.NET RegIIS version 4.0.30319
Administration utility to install and uninstal
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All righ
Start installing ASP.NET (4.0.30319.36392).
.........
```

Após isto, receberá a mensagem de que foi finalizado, então apenas de um refresh na aplicação dentro do IIS e rode, revise se está setado o pool correto.

Comment: obg, funcionou!

Comment: Sem problemas, eu que agradeço a pergunta, ajudará outros com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou aqui...